# Which one of these answers regarding functions is incorrect?

Tags: c++

So while I've been doing some lengthy compiles I decided to take the C++ general test on ODesk  and came across this question.

[image: This question]

If I'm not mistaken, given the wording (or lack thereof) **all** of these could be true.

**a.**

```
int Foo() { }
int Foo(int bar) { }
```

**b.**
Well, `return void;` would be incorrect semantically but functions can obviously have `void` return types.

```
void Foo() { }
```

**c.** This is the definition of inline functions, yes.

**d.**
Without going into much detail about the placement of the following elements,

```
typedef void (*Func)(int);

Func functions[2];

void Foo(int bar) { }
void Bar(int foo) { }

functions[0] = &Foo;
functions[1] = &Bar;
```

Further, you could always do this using [lambdas and functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477310/why-cant-i-create-a-vector-of-lambda-in-c11).

**e.**

```
void Foo(int& bar)
{
    ++bar;
}

int foobar = 5;
Foo(foobar);
```

**f.**

```
int bar = 5;

int& GetBar()
{
    return bar;
}

GetBar() = 6;
```

**g.**

```
int bar = 5;

int* GetBar()
{
    return &bar;
}

(*GetBar()) = 5;
```

---

I fail to see where this question has any *truly false* answers. Am I missing something?

<sub>Needless to say I ran out of time and failed the whole thing. I guess I'm a bad C++ programmer. :(</sub>

Comment: Came here to yell at some kid pasting homework, was pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Actually not all languages require that inline functions are expanded. "inline" is a compiler hint rather than a command in Delphi, and C, C++ [have exceptions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html). So "c" can be false as well. It might be more entertaining to write an answer showing how each statement can be wrong.

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ If only there was a text box. I want to go back and hit the "Report an issue with this question".

Comment: That is not an array of functions. That is an array of function pointers.

Comment: @immibis True, but the question doesn't really clarify (at least to me it didn't).

Comment: @Qix it quite clearly does not say "function pointers".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This whole question is dodgy. The question statement implies the possibility of multiple choices, while the radio buttons indicates a single choice.

Furthermore, b is pretty suspect, as void functions don't return anything.

D is also questionable, for as far as I know, you cannot have an array of functions. Sure, you can have an array of function pointers, but thats not exactly the same thing.

Comment: Right; D is like asking if you can call an `int`. Sure, if you cast it to a pointer and that pointer refers to a function...

Comment: I'm willing to bet D is the answer they are going for, but yes, the question is poor.

Comment: While `void` functions don't return any *value*, they still return the *type* `void`. Thus I say B is true.

Comment: @ThomasEding That's still really bad wording on their part. You don't `return void;`, but instead `return;`.

Answer (score 11):

Answer c) is also arguably false.

"Inline functions are expanded during compile time to avoid invocation overhead."

Firstly, the C++ compiler is permitted to ignore the `inline` hint by not expanding the functions at all.

Secondly, the stated "reason" for doing expansion is an oversimplification.  In fact, the real reason for doing the expansion (or not) is entirely in the hands of the compiler writer.

Comment: You're correct, but I was thinking about it in the sense of _'okay, the compiler has determined it **does** want to inline a function'_ rather than the `inline` hint.

Comment: Well, the compiler cannot completely ignore the hint. At least it's mandated effect, making an exception to ODR.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Yes it can.  *"No matter how you designate a function as inline, it is a request that the compiler is allowed to ignore: the compiler might inline-expand some, all, or none of the places where you call a function designated as inline."* - source https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/Inline-Functions

Comment: @StephenC: The request to expand it inline can be ignored, yes. I only said that the explicit exception to the ODR cannot.

Comment: I see.  I have updated the wording the of my answer

Answer (score 7):

> c. This is the definition of inline functions, yes.

That is not completely right.
Despite its name, the keyword `inline` does not guarantee that a function will be inlined. The only thing that you can be sure of is that the compiler will not complain if it sees the definition of an inline function multiple times.

So, strictly speaking, option C is incorrect, but I don't think it is the answer that the authors of the quiz expect, because there is an answer that is even more wrong.

> d. Without going into much detail about the placement of the following elements,
>
> ```
> typedef void (*Func)(int);
>
> Func functions[2];
>
> void Foo(int bar) { }
> void Bar(int foo) { }
>
> functions[0] = &Foo;
> functions[1] = &Bar;
> ```
>
> Further, you could always do this using lambdas and functors.

In your example, `functions` is an array of *pointers to* functions and not an array of functions themselves. Similarly, lambdas and functors are not really functions either. They are classes that respond to the function-call operator, but that doesn't make them functions in the eyes of the C++ language definition.

Functions in C++ are a bit like second-class citizens. You can define and call them, but as soon as you try to do something else with a function type (like create an array of them), you either get an error or they silently convert themselves in a pointer.

Comment: I agree with the D bit, but I was reading `c` as functions that have already been positively marked for inlining, versus the `inline` keyword itself. I understand `inline` is a hint.

Answer (score 4):

If anything, it would have to be **b**. You can't `return` a `void`, but you can return a `null`. Void on the function declaration should be there to notify the compiler of a lack of a returned value.

[Void Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type)

> **In C and C++**
>
> A function with void result type ends either by reaching the end of the function or by executing a return statement with no returned value. The void type may also appear as the sole argument of a function prototype to indicate that the function takes no arguments. Note that despite the name, in all of these situations, the void type serves as a unit type, not as a zero or bottom type, even though unlike a real unit type which is a singleton, the void type is said to comprise an empty set of values, and the language does not provide any way to declare an object or represent a value with type void.

Comment: -1: While `void` functions don't return any *value*, they still return the *type* `void`. Thus I say B is true.

Comment: Returning void is permitted under some circumstances. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3383090/25507).